# Hashset printing the values in same order every time?

Tags: java, hashset

Per  [HashSet java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time

Code :-

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("This is Tiger");
    set.add("This is Cat");
    set.add("This is Dog");
    set.add("This is Elephant");
    set.add("This is Parrot");



    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){

        for(String str:set){
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    }
```

When I executed  the above code any number of times, I see below  output

```
    This is Elephant
    This is Parrot
    This is Cat
    This is Dog
    This is Tiger
```

My question is when java docs says that HashSet  does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time then why I see above order as same any number of time I execute the program.

Is it doing internal ordering based on hash code of string ?

**Update :-**
Based on answers, looks like order will be predictable when set is static. 
When i say predictable it does not mean that retrieval order will be same as insertion order but whatever order returned first time, it will be same over time.

**Reasoning:-** Say I if am adding 5 static entries, it will fit those entries under bucket(nothing both some position in list/array) based on hashcode. Let's Elephant fits under 3rd bucket, Parrot - 5 bucket, Cat - 6th bucket, Dog - 9th bucket, Tiger - 10th bucket

Now If i add Giraffe, it gets fit to 8th bucket based on hash code > Now if i iterate it will iterate the entries from starting bucket. This will be constant over time. So if set is static order can be predictable.

I am not going to use Hashset for ordering but I have third party code putting static entries under HashSet which i can not change . I need to predict the order among those entries for some reason

Comment: It happens to be like that but you shouldn't assume it in your program.

Comment: You're confusing "does not guarantee that the order will remain constant" with "guarantees that the order will vary over time". These two mean very different things. It iterates over its internal structure  made of buckets, lists and trees, and you shouldn't assume anything about this ordering.

Comment: Add the first three elements to your `set`; iterate your `Set`. Then add `Elephant`... why does it become the first? Is that consistent with the initial order? Why not?

Comment: To simplify, if in further releases of Java, the implementation of `HashSet` has changed, they warned you about it.

Comment: @YassinHajaj The problem is not just future Java releases. The order may very well change in the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time

It happens that you have a static `Set`.
The guarantee comes into place when you modify your existing `Set` with new additions:

And you are right. Your program will return as expected.

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("This is Tiger");
    set.add("This is Cat");
    set.add("This is Dog");
    set.add("This is Elephant");
    set.add("This is Parrot");

    /*
      This is Elephant
      This is Parrot
      This is Cat
      This is Dog
      This is Tiger
     */
    for (String str : set) {
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

Now let us add a new entry, like a giraffe in the `Set`.

```
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("This is Tiger");
    set.add("This is Cat");
    set.add("This is Dog");
    set.add("This is Elephant");
    set.add("This is Parrot");
    set.add("This is Giraffe");

    /*
      This is Elephant
      This is Parrot
      This is Cat
      This is Giraffe
      This is Dog
      This is Tiger
     */
    for (String str : set) {
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

The order changed of the elements.

The thing to keep in mind is that you should not rely on the iteration order of the set, because the **insertion** order is not predictable, as opposite to a predictable insertion order like `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: Do you mean when I have static set, order is predictable.  When i say predictable it does not mean that retrieval order will be same as insertion order but whatever order returned first time, it will be same over time. Even once you added  `Giraffe`, the order you got and I got on my machine is same.Now execute the same program, number of times, it will be same. Is n't it ?

Comment: @user3198603 Yes, if you that this `Set` elements is never going to change, then it's predictable. But again, I highly advice against relying on that. If you want to have rely on the order that you inserted your elements and be able to retrieve them in the same order, then use `LinkedHashSet`. HashSet relies on hashes, so once you add something in the set, the hash table is recalculated based on the hashCode of your type (in your case String), which takes the default hashCode of String. If you want some other other, than you want to create a new object and add your own `hashCode` and `equals`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the understanding of the guarantees which is addressed in the comments and other answers, there is a built-in feature of `HashMap` (which is `HashSet`) based on which influences the order of values pretty much:

> Implementation notes.
>
> This map usually acts as a binned (bucketed) hash table, but
>   when bins get too large, they are transformed into bins of
>   TreeNodes, each structured similarly to those in
>   java.util.TreeMap. Most methods try to use normal bins, but
>   relay to TreeNode methods when applicable (simply by checking
>   instanceof a node).  Bins of TreeNodes may be traversed and
>   used like any others, but additionally support faster lookup
>   when overpopulated. However, since the vast majority of bins in
>   normal use are not overpopulated, checking for existence of
>   tree bins may be delayed in the course of table methods.

This effectively means that after certain number of values in one bit, the `HashMap` will restructure the bucket from linked-list-like to tree-map-like. Which will influence the order of values in iteration.